# Can't get media query to function

Tags: css, media-queries

I can't seem to get a pair of @media queries to work. Tried several pieces of code to no avail. I'm attempting to position an audio player on all devices, however, for some unknown reason to me, the player will not move under a media query. If you go to 24hournews.news on a desktop or laptop, you'll see the issue. The player is way off to the right, and shouldn't be.  The code for the phone platform works fine. Here's the pertinent code:

```
img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
    }

/* top right */
.top-right {
position: absolute;
top: 170px;        
left: 190px;
    } 

/* top phone */
.top-phone {
 position: absolute;
 top: 275px;
 right: 35px;        
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
<div class="top-right">
<script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
</div>
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
<div class="top-right">
<script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
</div>
}

</style>
</head>
<body> 
<img src="24logo.jpg"> 
<div class="top-phone">
<script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Media queries wrap CSS selectors, not HTML elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Why do you have HTML in your media queries?

Comment: As others have commented, media queries are of `CSS` syntax and meant to wrap `CSS` selectors and their attributes. Having an `HTML` element to load an external `JS` file just doesn't work. If you're trying to position the audio player responsively depending on viewport sizes, place relevant `CSS` selector and positioning intentions in there.

Comment: While it isn't possible the way you tried, which is mixing CSS and HTML, what you want is possible, and my answer below shows how it could be achieved using `id` attributes and `display` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change css properties in media queries , not html elements.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
img {
//styles
    }

/* top right */
.top-right {
//styles
    } 


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
img {
//styles
    }

/* top right */
.top-right {
//styles
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only put CSS in media queries, not HTML. What you want to do is show one piece of HTML for one media query and a different piece for another.

To do this, you will need to give each piece its own `id` and then control their `display` property in a media query. The code below does what you want:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* top right */

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 190px;
}


/* top phone */

.top-phone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 275px;
  right: 35px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #query1 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #query2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="top-right" id="query1">
    <script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
  </div>

  <div class="top-right" id="query2">
    <script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
  </div>


  <img src="24logo.jpg">
  <div class="top-phone">
    <script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>
```

Note that, in addition to the changes already described, I've removed an out of place `</head>` tag, as well as correcting the `body` so that it wraps around the other elements.

Comment: You do not need to give each element its own `ID`. The OP needs to place the HTML markup for `.top-right` into the HTML markup, and then use the `media` queries to target `.top-right`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you need to target your HTML element's class in your `media` query:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* top right */

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 190px;
}


/* top phone */

.top-phone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 275px;
  right: 35px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px; /* CHANGE THIS VALUE */
    left: 190px; /* CHANGE THIS VALUE */
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; /* CHANGE THIS VALUE */
    left: 190px; /* CHANGE THIS VALUE */
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="24logo.jpg">
<div class="top-phone">
  <div class="top-right">
    <script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/056cfb4.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```